# How do I disable csd-wacom?

Tags: process, services, kill

I would also like to know how to permanently disable csd-wacom since I don't have a Wacom tablet and csd-wacom is wasting resources and [the question regarding how to disable it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/657742/80216) wasn't answered.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is here in this blog https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/cleanup-ubuntu-2004-lts-henrik-holst/